# How to create an Identity Provider using the Metadata API

Tags: apex, metadata-api, identity-provider

I see all other types like AuthProviders but don't see a way to create an `Identity Provider` in [Salesforce Metadata API.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_types_list.htm).

**Is there none?! And why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot automate the enablement/config of a built-in identity provider via APIs. The APIs do not exist for doing so. The likely reason for non-existence of APIs is security + change management. Enabling the identity provider significantly changes the security posture of the org and while it might be a safe change, it's a type of change that should be done by a human admin (checks+balances). The change management aspect is also important. Just about everything about the identity provider represents an external interface that would be relied on by 3rd parties. If you were able to change it, the integration with these 3rd parties might break.

In terms of what needs to be done by admin to set up an identity provider in a new org:

1. Enable it (via a button) on Identity Provider config screen (Security Controls > Identity Provider)
2. Once enabled, the identity provider will be automatically associated with a newly auto-generated keypair. The admin could generate a new keypair and make it active.

Only step 1 is mandatory, step 2 is optional. Even though there's no API for automation of steps 1 or 2, step 1 is a simple enough task that screen-scraping it wouldn't be a lot of effort.

Comment: With which field in SamlSSOConfig do I set and activate it?

Comment: Auth providers represent external entities. If you mean SF acting as an identity provider, then there's no way to manipulate it via Metadata or any other API.

Comment: I mean what you enable in setup > identify providers

Comment: If you add to your question the crucial opening question that it CANNOT be done via Code or Api (and maybe why) I can click "Accept" ;-)

Comment: @RobertSösemann See update